# Writing to .bss section in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm having a `.bss` section in which I have a buffer of 8 bytes inside it. Now, I'm looking for a way to store the number `2` inside the buffer without issuing a system call. Is that possible ?

My attempt which doesn't work:

```
        .section .text

        .section .bss

        .lcomm SAMPLE_BUFFER, 8

        .globl _start

_start:

        movl $2,SAMPLE_BUFFER

        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

On execution:

```
  $ as --32 buffer.s -o buffer.o
  $ ld -m elf_i386 buffer.o -o buffer
  $ ./buffer
  fish: “./buffer” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure to switch back to the `.text` section before emitting the machine code for `_start`.  As is, you place `_start` in `.bss` which is not executable, crashing your program.

Apart from that, your code seems correct.

Comment: Also note that `.lcomm` knows to put things into `.bss` automatically, you don't even need to switch away from `.text` at all.